# javafx : pass parameter to the eventhandler function in fxml file

Tags: javafx, fxml, eventhandler

Is there a way to call the `event handler` method from the `fxml file` which holds `parameter`? please find the files:

My Fxml Looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.cognizant.iotworkbench.View.AddImageController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="270.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Add Sensor" />
      <BorderPane layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="602.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <left>
            <HBox fx:id="source" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fx:id="sourceimg" fitHeight="114.0" fitWidth="142.0" onDragDetected="#setUpGestureSource" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="file:Images/Project.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </left>
         <right>
            <HBox fx:id="target" onDragDropped="#setUpGestureTarget" onDragOver="#setUpGestureTarget" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </right>
      </BorderPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

My controller class looks like

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 */
public class AddImage implements Initializable,ControlledScreen {

    ScreensController myController;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
 @FXML
    final HBox target=new HBox();
    @FXML
    final HBox source=new HBox();

    @FXML
    final ImageView sourceimg=new ImageView();



  @FXML
        public void setUpGestureSource()
        {
            System.out.println("source");
        source.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler <MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                /* drag was detected, start drag-and-drop gesture*/
                System.out.println("onDragDetected");

                /* allow MOVE transfer mode */
                Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);

                /* put a string on dragboard */
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                Image sourceImage = sourceimg.getImage();
               content.putImage(sourceImage);
               db.setContent(content);

                event.consume();
            }
        });
        }
        @FXML
        public void setUpGestureTarget(){
            System.out.println("target");
        target.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler <DragEvent>() {
            @Override
             public void handle(DragEvent event) {

                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();

                if(db.hasImage()){
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
                }

                event.consume();
            }
        });
         target.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler <DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {

                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();

                if(db.hasImage()){

                    insertImage(db.getImage(), target);

                    event.setDropCompleted(true);
                }else{
                    event.setDropCompleted(false);
                }

                event.consume();
            }
        });
}
       void insertImage(Image i, HBox hb){

        ImageView iv = new ImageView();
        iv.setImage(i);

        setUpGestureSource();
        hb.getChildren().add(iv);
    }
    @Override
    public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent) {

         myController=screenParent;
    }
        @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    



}
```

Drag and Drop event is not getting fired. I dont know what's wrong with the code. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All methods that are annotated with `@FXML` *may or may not* have a parameter. If you need a parameter, you can directly pass the `specific Event` as a parameter to the method.

Let us take an example and say you have an `onDragOver` event added for a HBox  in the fxml.

```
<HBox fx:id="targetBox" onDragOver="#setupGestureTarget">
...
</HBox>
```

Then you may have a method which does the needful inside the controller class.

```
@FXML
public void setupGestureTarget(DragEvent event) {
     Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
     if(db.hasImage()){
           event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
     }
     event.consume();
}
```

If you need the source node for which the method was called, you can get an access to it by `getSource()` of the event, then type-caste it to `Node`.

```
public void setupGestureTarget(DragEvent event) {
     ...
     ((Node)event.getSource()).setId("myHbox");
     System.out.println(targetBox.getId()); // Prints - myHbox
}
```

**Note :** For using methods specific to `HBox`, you can type-caste it to a `HBox` instead of a `Node`.

---

### **EDIT** - As per user comments and updates

There are multiple issues with your approach. Let me address them all.

1.Values to the fields annotated with `@FXML` are injected while the FXML is getting loaded and should not carry `new` keyword.

```
@FXML
final HBox target=new HBox();
```

should be replaced by

```
@FXML
final HBox target;
```

2.As I have already stated your method can have a parameter which defines the Event. So the methods `setUpGestureSource()` and `setUpGestureTarget()` can be defined as :

```
@FXML
public void setUpGestureSource(DragEvent event) {
...
}

@FXML
public void setUpGestureTarget(DragEvent event) {
...
}
```

3.The method `setUpGestureSource` is called when a `drag-event` occurs on the `ImageView`, so you don't need to add *another* `EventHandler` for it.

```
@FXML
public void setUpGestureSource(MouseEvent event) {
     /* drag was detected, start drag-and-drop gesture*/
     System.out.println("onDragDetected");

     * allow MOVE transfer mode */
     Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);

     /* put a string on dragboard */
     ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
     Image sourceImage = sourceimg.getImage();
     content.putImage(sourceImage);
     db.setContent(content);
     event.consume();
}
```

Similarly, change the other method as well.

Comment: i am trying to drag and drop a image from Hbox1 to Hbox2. i am calling this method for the same                                                                              void insertImage(Image i, HBox hb){
         
        ImageView iv = new ImageView();
        iv.setImage(i);
         
        setupGestureSource(iv);
        hb.getChildren().add(iv);
    }   this function will take a copy of the image from the source and drop it to the target hbox. but i am not able to the same since the setUpGestureSource(iv) has imageview parameter.

Comment: i tried the way you suggested..but the drag and drop event is not getting fired

Comment: Please edit the question and add what you have tried and what is not working for you.

Comment: I have edited my question. please take a look at it.

Comment: i wanna add a click event to the image dropped in the target Hbox. how to achieve that?

Comment: Please ask a separate question if you have any further questions.